# What exactly was the Everlasting Darkness?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In *The Silmarillion*, the Oath of Fëanor called the Everlasting Darkness on any who broke the Oath.

This was clearly something greatly to be feared. What exactly was it?

Comment: The absence of Iluvatar.

Comment: @MarkOlson That's plausible,  being a recen-ish Catholic definition of Hell, but is there evidence?

Comment: Imagine a really brief, really bright flash. It's the opposite of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the

## Void

Same place which Morgoth was banished.

The Void was also known as the Abyss, the Outer Void, the Timeless Void, the Everlasting Dark, the Ancient Darkness, and "the Outside".<sup>[1](https://www.tor.com/2018/09/19/morgoth-is-rendered-null-and-void-in-an-all-out-war-of-wrath/)</sup>

Comment: Probably 'the bottomless pit' referenced in Revelation (since Tolkien based it on Roman Catholic beliefs)

Comment: Is it really a void though after Morgoth starts squatting there? Probably Abyss, Dark, and Pit become more technically descriptive once the Void starts getting filled up.